# My code uses an API with secret key in several locations. How can I upload the code to GitHub without also uploading my key?

Tags: javascript, github

The project is a Vue SPA and a couple of my components have to make GET requests to an API with a secret key. I currently want to upload the project to GitHub pages, however, I don't want to upload the key.

I've read that I need to create a file that should contain a variable with my key and then just use that variable in the place of the secret key, however, I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the key client-side then you expose it to every user of the application.

Putting it in a variable just means it only appears in one place in the source code. It is still visible there and in every request sent to the API (where it can easily be found with the Network tab in the browser's developer tools).

To keep it secret you need to write *server-side* code to access the API, and then expose the data to your Vue app through some other mechanism (typically a web service of your own).

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that if I only have a front-end SPA that consumes an API from a third party and I want to host that SPA, I can't do it unless I expose the API key for the third party API?

Comment: Correct. Typically you will find that CORS permission is not provided for APIs that need secret keys.

Comment: I'm using Google Maps API and Google Places API and I do have my own back-end. Whenever I want to get all sights in a certain city I do have to make a GET request to my back-end so it can make a GET request to Google Places API because I don't have CORS permission if doing this from the front-end. HOWEVER, some of the functionality doesn't require me to make the GET request from my back-end and when this is the case, I just make the request from the front-end. For example https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=

Answer (score 0):

You can use environment file that's not a part of the source code and load it in your front end code via [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package or similar

Comment: I agree. ENV files are often used in this case because add security with functionality and avoid complexity

Comment: The .ENV file will still need to be uploaded to github though and the OP wants to use github pages to host his project.  The .ENV file will be visible to all who check the repository correct? That is what the entire question was about.

Comment: you upload a .ENV.dist which (look at my answer) is a template filled at deploy time with the right values.

Comment: It'll still be visible in the front end regardless of anything done to keep it out of the public git repo.

Comment: It depends by the API and application type, where we have API that can provide a signature like AWS this is viable way, when a server has to manage API auth request and response for every client it could become an unnecessary bottleneck. Data sensibility exchanged with the API are also a parameter. Retrieving Instagram photos is not the same that retrieving customer invoices.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot rely on a server to store it as suggested above, you can store it in an ENV variable template.

*auth.ENV.dist*

```
NODE_ENV=''
PORT=''
# Set your database/API connection information here
API_KEY=''
API_URL=''
```

**Notice: this is a common practice to set a auth key in a .ENV file and is far more common that retrieving it from a server** for a variety of reason. IE least but not last reason: for retrieving in a safe way those parameters you have to store another auth token or rely on other parameters (IP or similar) related to the deploy environment.

There are [tons of articles](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/making-your-node-js-work-everywhere-with-environment-variables-2da8cdf6e786) covering the topic, just look where and how .ENV files are used.

This also allows to split behavior of your auth in (IE) test, staging and production environment.

**EDIT:**

[This article](https://medium.com/poka-techblog/the-best-way-to-store-secrets-in-your-app-is-not-to-store-secrets-in-your-app-308a6807d3ed) is very complete and take in account a lot of scenarios with advantages and drawbacks, it also exposes the architecture of a serverside management of keys.

Comment: The .ENV file will still need to be uploaded to github though and the OP wants to use github pages to host his project.  The .ENV file will be visible to all who check the repository correct? That was what the entire question was about.

Comment: .ENV.dist parameters are empty on the repo and populated at deploy time.

Comment: OK, let's assume it is populated at deploy time (how you do that on Github Pages I have no idea) … the env file is then delivered to the client for the SPA to us … so it is visible to the user of the browser … so it isn't secret any more.

Comment: You are right @Quentin but security and complexity has to be balanced to the scope, IMHO. Serverside solution is better for sure but sometimes you have to balance security with complexity

Comment: If you're balancing those then this approach adds significant complexity for absolutely zero security.

Comment: I repeat, I 100% agree with you but "zero security" for thrusted users and not sensitive APIs sometimes fits. IE: Google directions API: yes, you can proxy the entire Google directions API serverside but is equal to 
shoot with a bazooka to a mosquito.